# Migrating a project to VS2022 from VS2013 and I get an error related to inability to find a few files (MSVCRTD.lib and ucrtd.lib)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

I am having an issue and I am hoping there's a better solution than the one I used..

I am migrating a C/C++ project from VS2013 into VS2022.  I went through all of the procedure to change the tools, etc, and I can compile but I receive the following 2 errors when linking:

```
 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRTD.lib'
 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib'
 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'uafxcwd.lib'
 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcmtd.lib'
```

I was able to get these to go away by adding some lines to the "additional library directories" within the project. After this it worked fine..

MSVCRTD.lib ->  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\lib\x86

ucrtd.lib   ->  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x86

uafxcwd.lib  -> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\atlmfc\lib\x86

libcmtd.lib  -> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\lib\x86

But, it seems like this shouldn't be the only way get this to work. Is there something I am not doing that would allow these to be found in a more "proper" way? Adding these crazy folders just seems like the wrong way to do this..

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is the wrong way.  This is normally configured in Project > Properties > VC++ Directories.  Why the migration went so poorly is not obvious without seeing the project file content.  Start VS2022 again and start a new C++ project, then compare the properties of the two, focusing on the General and VC++ Directories categories.

Comment: Thanks for the respons,e i will do that, make a new project and see what the VC++ Directories differences are..  thanks!

Comment: Well, it looks like the actual problem was pretty simple, the "inherit from parent or project default" was not checked, so it didnt pick up anything from the migration.. i found this by doing what was suggested, It is working now!